# PHP String and Numeric Sum

Tags: php, for-loop, echo

I have a string like: `00030000` and need to increment this with loop.

```
$start = "00030000";

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i + $start;
}
```

It prints this

```
30001 
30002 
30003 
30004 
//...
```

This is understood but how can I get following result?

```
00030001 
00030002 
00030003 
00030004 
//...
```

Comment: Also, it may be off-topic. but be aware that in PHP `030` is not `30`, but `24`. This is because PHP threats numbers starting with a 0 as octals (except when the 0 is followed with a decimal point).

Comment: Why does not `echo "000", $i + $start;` work for you? You always have three zeroes in front if you look closely. Just take care of the formatting with the output, not the calculation.

Comment: @hakra this is one case where the starting number has padded zeros. Many other may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$start = "00030000";
$startLen = strlen($start);
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo str_pad($i + $start, $startLen, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Zero pad it to your required length using [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$start = "00030000";

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $sum = $i + $start;
    echo str_pad($sum, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Output:

```
00030001
00030002
00030003
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strpad or [sprintf](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to get this.

```
$input = "30";
echo str_pad($input, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // produces "0030"
```

Answer (score 1):

for fun:

```
$start = "00030000";
$start = '_' . $start;

for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
    echo ltrim($start++, '_');
    echo "\n";
}
```

Please don't actually use that code. While it works perfectly and takes advantage of a [documented feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) of php, its bewildering to most people who would read it(which makes it bad code). Use one of the answers that uses str_pad()

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = "00030000";
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo sprintf( "%08u\n", $i + $start );
 }
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.